# object literal variable

Tags: javascript, variables, select, literals

```
var example= {
        'fr' : {
            name: "France",
            country: "europe",
        },
        'es' : {
            name: "Espana",
            pre: "europe",
        },
    };
```

I would like to find an array name using a variable. Here there is an example that doesn't work:

```
var select = 'country';
console.log(example['fr'].select);
```

I would like that this piece of code return "europe", but it doesn't. How could I do in a simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var select = 'country';
console.log(example['fr'][select]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log(example['fr'][select]);
```

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using wrong syntax. You have a two-dimensional array, i.e. array nested in another array. So, the expression `example['fr']` returns you an array with two members:

```
{
   name: "France",
   country: "europe",
}
```

and you have to get the value bound to `country` key from it like this:

```
ar2 = example['fr'];
console.log(ar[select]);
```

or to make it more concise:

```
console.log(example['fr'][select]);
```

directly referring to the element of the innermost array without using a temporary variable.